Set the Maximum Depth of Chained Queueable Jobs not working?
This Set the Maximum Depth of Chained Queueable Jobs (Generally Available) is GA and documented to work in:

Where: This change applies to Lightning Experience and Salesforce Classic in Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer editions.

When I try this in my scratch org ("edition": "Developer",) using API 62 Apex:
AsyncOptions asyncOptions = new AsyncOptions();
asyncOptions.MaximumQueueableStackDepth = 50;
asyncOptions.MinimumQueueableDelayInMinutes = delayMinutes;
System.enqueueJob(q, asyncOptions);

I get this error:

Cannot reset Maximum Queueable Stack Depth in a queueable

Has anyone seen this working? Any idea why it isn't working in my situation?
(There is an example of it not working here Salesforce Queueable AsyncOptions.)

Does that code run also when chaining the queueable? Only the first enqueue should set the maxDepth, while chaining should be done via System.enqueueJob(q); without the maxDepth

Thanks @RubenDG - that could be the problem. I'll try it.

Hi @RubenDG yes that was my problem. I see that the example code only sets the value on the first enqueue but does not call out the importance of that. Please post as an answer and I'll vote/accept it. Thank-you!

AsyncOptions.MaximumQueueableStackDepth must be set only the first time you enqueue a queueable, while every time that queueable enqueues itself (chaining) MaximumQueueableStackDepth must not be set, that's why it throws

Cannot reset Maximum Queueable Stack Depth in a queueable

Anyway setting the delay in minutes is fine.
I.E.
public class MyQueueable implements Queueable {
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        // something
        if (!Test.isRunningTest() && otherConditions) {
            // Chaining without overriding MaximumQueueableStackDepth
            System.enqueue(this, 0);
        }
    }

    public static void enqueueAfter(Integer minutes) {
         AsyncOptions asyncOptions = new AsyncOptions();
         asyncOptions.MaximumQueueableStackDepth = 50;
         asyncOptions.MinimumQueueableDelayInMinutes = minutes;
         System.enqueueJob(new MyQueueable(), asyncOptions);
    }
}


MyQueueable.enqueueAfter(1);

